# How do you change the visual editor's background color?

Tags: visual-editor

I have a Wordpress site in which the background color is black and the text is white.   The site is fine, but it's a pain trying to edit content in the visual editor as the background is white (same color as the text).  I end up having to tell users to use the HTML view or write up the content in black color text and then at the end just select all the text and flip it to white (in which case many of them freak out and think their text is now deleted!)

**How do I change the background color of the editor to black (or any other color) so that the content can be readable if the text color is to be white?**

Comment: +1 for the good Question & +1+ for the great Answers it got!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

similar to the answer by GavinR, using the wordpress [`add_editor_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style) function; (as implemented in Twenty Ten and Twenty Eleven)

in functions.php of your theme, add:

```
add_editor_style();
```

then create an editor-style.css in your theme folder:

```
.mceContentBody.wp-editor {     
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, add a CSS file in your theme directory (I'm calling it tiny.css). Then add the following to your theme's functions.php:

```
// Add custom styles to TinyMCE editor
if ( ! function_exists('tdav_css') ) {
    function tdav_css($wp) {
        $wp .= ',' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/tiny.css';
        return $wp;
    }
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'tdav_css' );
```

Finally, add this CSS to tiny.css

```
.mceContentBody.wp-editor {
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

... replacing #000000 with the [HTML color code](http://html-color-codes.info/) of what color you'd like it to be.

Comment: First rule of WP hacking - never edit core files. First person to post the correct way to restyle the editor gets my vote..

Comment: Great point! I have modified this so that it does not modify core WordPress files.