# Editor background colour in full screen

Tags: visual-editor, add-editor-style

In this Q&A, [How do you change the visual editor's background color?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25355), it is shown how to modify WordPress' editor background colour.
My question is how can I modify the editor's background colour, in full screen mode? (also called "distraction free" mode).
The solution in the linked thread does not work for full screen editor mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problems are solved using [Chrome Inspector](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firefox Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Inspecting the element, we get the necessary ID's or Classes to add in the stylesheet.

[image: chrome inspector]

So, `.mceContentBody.wp-fullscreen-editor` is the one we need to address in the theme file `editor-style.css`:

```
.mceContentBody.wp-editor, .mceContentBody.wp-fullscreen-editor {     
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff; 
}
```